# Retrofit call using abstraction with kotlin is not calling onChange

Tags: android, kotlin, retrofit2

I want to abstract the retrofit call, so I don't need to write the same boiler plate code when I need a request.

#### The abstraction

```
open class NetworkCall<T> {
    lateinit var call: Call<T>
    var result: MutableLiveData<Resource<T>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun makeCall(call: Call<T>) {
        this.call = call
        val callBackKt = CallBackKt<T>()
        callBackKt.result.value = Resource.loading(null)
        this.call.enqueue(callBackKt)
        result = callBackKt.result
    }

    class CallBackKt<T> : Callback<T> {
        var result: MutableLiveData<Resource<T>> = MutableLiveData()

        override fun onFailure(call: Call<T>, t: Throwable) {
            result.value = Resource.error()//APIError()
            t.printStackTrace()
        }

        override fun onResponse(call: Call<T>, response: Response<T>) {
            if (response.isSuccessful) {
                result.value = Resource.success(response.body())
            }
            else {
                result.value = Resource.error()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

#### Repository

```
class DetailsRepository(val application: Application) {
    private val myListDao =
        AppDatabase.getDatabase(application)?.MyListDao()
    var movie: MutableLiveData<Resource<DetailsDTO>> = MutableLiveData()

    fun getDetails(id: Int) {
        val networkCall = NetworkCall<DetailsDTO>()
        networkCall.makeCall(Apifactory.tmdbApi.getDetails(id))
        movie = networkCall.result
    }
}
```

#### ViewModel

```
class DetailsViewModel(application: Application) : AndroidViewModel(application) {
    private val repository: DetailsRepository = DetailsRepository(application)
    internal var movie: LiveData<Resource<DetailsDTO>> = repository.movie

    fun insert(myListItem: MyListItem) {
        repository.insert(myListItem)
    }

    fun fetchDetails(id: Int) {
        repository.getDetails(id)
    }

}
```

#### Activity

```
 viewModel.movie.observe(this, Observer {
            it?.apply {
                detail_title.text = data?.title
            }
        })
```

#### Log with in every method says it's being called in right order and that the request is working fine. Althoght onChange is not being called.

```
fetchDetails called
getDetails called
makeCall called
onResponse successful, result.value.data = DetailsDTO(adult=false, backdrop_path=/y8lEIjYZCi2VFP4ixtHSn2klpth.jpg, ... 
...
```

What would be done wrong?

Comment: Ideally movie = networkCall.result should be movie.value = networkCall.result

Comment: ```movie.value = networkCall.result``` doesn't work either. Since ```movie``` works as a pointer for the value to be presented on screen it should work. I think that something is holding the value from being returned from the abstraction.

Comment: Try returning a live data at getDetails in the repository. From the ViewModel, observe to this live data. And publish the status to the Mutablelive data in the ViewModel.

Comment: Isn't it a bad practice to observe a ```livedata``` from the ```viewmodel```? A got it working by doing something that I also think is not a good practice: I moved the ```makeCall``` to the ```viewmodel```. But I why does it works now?